# Toggle SCHEDULED keyword

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am looking for an elisp function that will toggle scheduling for the current headline either to  or not at all. Something like this:

```
If (SCHEDULED == Nil | SCHEDULED > <today>)
   Set SCHEDULED to <today>
Else if (SCHEDULED <= <today>)
   Set SCHEDULED to Nil
End If
```

The idea is to assign this function to a key combination (something like C-c C-t) so that I can quickly send (or remove) items from a Custom agenda view (the "Today" list). I would then font lock scheduled items in my `projects.org` file, to add a visual queue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This feature is already built-in.

- `C-c C-s` to add a scheduled date.  The default is today, so if you want today, then just press the enter key after the foregoing keyboard shortcut.
- `C-u C-c C-s` to remove a scheduled date.

Here is the doc-string for `org-schedule`:

```
Insert the SCHEDULED: string with a timestamp to schedule a TODO item.
With one universal prefix argument, remove any scheduling date from the item.
With two universal prefix arguments, prompt for a delay cookie.
With argument TIME, scheduled at the corresponding date.  TIME can
either be an Org date like "2011-07-24" or a delta like "+2d".
```

Here is the doc-string for `org-agenda-schedule`:

```
Schedule the item at point.
ARG is passed through to `org-schedule'.
```

Here is a link to the section in the manual entitled "**Inserting deadlines or schedules**":

http://orgmode.org/manual/Inserting-deadline_002fschedule.html

Comment: Thanks @lawlist. I was hoping to figure out how to use `org-schedule` in an elisp statement... It looks like it can be called with arguments?

Comment: `(org-schedule 'remove)` or `(org-schedule nil TIME)` or `(org-schedule nil "")`  A blank string is will become the current date if so desired.

Comment: Perfect! Do you also happen to know how to set the scheduled keyword to <today> using (org-schedule)?

Comment: My bad . . . I have an older version.  This will work for newer versions of org-mode to remove a scheduled:  `(org-schedule '(4))`  Can you educate me please regarding how org-mode knows that a keyword in the title relates to a task with a scheduled timestamp -- is there a variable or something where scheduled keywords are defined?

Comment: Found the relevant source code on why `'(4)` works: https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/9bc0cc7fb3285d9a1eb19bd4ce528e751240311e/lisp/org.el#L10397